# Checks if all items are negative

Tags: java

This piece of code checks to see if all the values within an array are all negative and returns true if they all are.

```
public static boolean allNegatives(int[] a) {

  if(a == null) {

      return false;

   }

    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if(a[i] > 0)
            return false;
    } return true;
}
```

Comment: What's the typical and maximum size of your array?

Answer (score 10):

With java 8 you can reduce your code using a more functional programming. It would be something like next. You could even reduce it to one line:

```
public static boolean allNegatives(int[] a) {
     //@bowmore suggestion edit
     return a != null && Arrays.stream(a).allMatch(i -> i < 0);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

There are some things I would make differently:

- The identation  is really inconsistent. Sometimes there are random line breaks without any apparent reasoning.
- There are missing parenthesis at the if-statement. This is error-prone when adding more statements
- The naming of the method looks strange. You are checking for nonPositive values instead of negative values (think about the value zero, it is not positive but also not negative)
- The for-loop has no direct purpose, i.e., you can use a foreach loop or even streams if you like that more
- The null-case is strangely handled: If there are no values, then all of them are negative

  ```
  public static boolean allArrayValuesNonPositive(int[] valueArray) {
      if (valueArray == null) {
          return false;
      }
      for (int value : valueArray) {
          if (value > 0) {
              return false;
          }
      }
      return true;
  }
  ```

I still don't like the return false in the case of a null-value in my solution.

Comment: In my opinion passing `null` should throw a `NullPointerException`. A `null` array is not the same thing as an empty array.

Comment: Your bullets are useful components to improve. Especially the `naming of the method` would turn the pages, cognitively and algorithmically.

Answer (score 3):

Your code again for easy direct comparison:

```
public static boolean allNegatives(int[] a) {

  if(a == null) {

      return false;

   }

    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if(a[i] > 0)
            return false;
    } return true;
}
```

Let's first fix the formatting (remove pointless empty lines, fix inconsistent indentation, put `return true` on its own line, add spaces after `if` and `for`).

```
public static boolean allNegatives(int[] a) {
  if (a == null) {
    return false;
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (a[i] > 0)
      return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Not sure about the inconsistent braces. I probably wouldn't use any here (except for the method's), but others and style guides might add braces for the inner `if` (not sure, I'm no Java coder).

There are two bugs:

- There are really only two reasonable ways to treat a `null` input: As erroneous, in which case you'd better throw an exception. Or as ok but obviously without content, in which case you'd treat it like an empty array, i.e., return `true`, not `false` (your code already does return `true` for empty arrays, and [that's the right thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_quantification#The_empty_set)).
- You return `false` only when you see a *positive* value, but 0 isn't negative, either. So change `> 0` to `>= 0`. I see Tobias [already pointed this out](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/164178/228314) but chose to change the method name from "negative" to "nonpositive" instead. In my opinion, if the implementation disagrees with the specification, and the specification is legitimate (i.e., not inconsistent or against standards or in some other way suspicious), then it's the implementation that's wrong, not the specification. And in this case, the specification is even threefold: title, text and method name all say "negative".

You could also use an enhanced `for` statement instead of looping by index, as you're really not interested in the index, only in the elements.

Final code:

```
public static boolean allNegatives(int[] a) {
  if (a == null) {
    return true;
  }
  for (int i : a) {
    if (i >= 0) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

And a fixed version of the top-voted answer:

```
public static boolean allNegatives(int[] a) {
  return a == null || Arrays.stream(a).allMatch(i -> i < 0);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not happy with the answers that suggest shorter code is better.

In my jaded opinion as a very old maintenance programmer, the decision about what to do with a null argument should be separated from the processing of a non-null array.

The question of whether an empty array is valid, and if so what value should be returned, is also open to discussion. It should be an explicit decision, the method should not happen to return true just as a quirk of the code.

The question of whether to use a simple loop or a stream is perhaps conditioned by the answer to a query against the original post about likely array sizes. Streams are, as I understand it, intended to allow for some degree of parallisation, so for a larger array on a system with enough processors this may be better, but I have no idea about what the values for "larger" and "enough" would be.

In general, I'd go for simplicity and clarity, so my solution will use a (foreach) loop.

I'd agree that the formatting could be improved - I'm another believer that all "if"s should have braced statements (again the maintenance programmer in me).

I also hate single character names, though here I don't think we know enough about context to suggest a better name for the array.

My solution below assumes that a null argument is invalid and so is an empty array.

```
   /**
    * @param a array of int values - in a more complete context, this name would be more meaningful
    * @return true if the array is non-null, non-empty and all elements are < 0
    * @throws NullPointerException if the argument is null
    * @throws IllegalArgumentException if the argument is an empty array
    */
  public static boolean allElementsAreNegative(int[] a) throws NullPointerException, IllegalArgumentException {
    if (a == null) {
      throw new NullPointerException("You must pass a non-null array");
    }

    if (a.length == 0) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("The array must have at least one element");
    }

    for (int element : a) {
      if (element >= 0) { // non-negative
        return false;
      }
    }
    
    return true;
  }
```

Comment: Why would an empty array be invalid? There's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: I've taken the decision that it's invalid as I don't know whether to interpret it as a) all elements meet the requirement (as there's none that violate it) or b) no elements meet the requirement (as there are no elements at all). You could argue either way, in my view.

With a more detailed specification, I would have made a different choice. Even then, I would suggest that there should be a test for the empty array case, and a comment explaining why the result should be "true" (or "false" as the case may be).

Comment: The task is just about "all". So it's true. You're explicitly going against the standard in math/compsci/programming. For math, see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_quantification#The_empty_set) again, and for example for Java, try `IntStream.empty().allMatch(i -> whatever)`, which happily tells you `true` (regardless of what `whatever` you use). Just like for example `IntStream.empty().sum()` happily tells you `0`. They're not like `IntStream.empty().min()` or `IntStream.empty().average()`, ...

Comment: ... which *do* have an issue with empty input, which is why their return types are `OptionalInt` and `OptionalDouble`, respectively (and they return empty ones for empty input).

Comment: I'm neither a mathematician nor a computer scientist :-)  and I can imagine that in a real commercial application, I'd want clarification other than "vacuuous truth"...

Comment: Like I just said, it's not "just" math/compsci, it's also the standard in practical programming like in Java's `IntStream.empty().allMatch(i -> whatever)`.

Comment: I accept the points you're making, but it doesn't alter my position. In real commercial programming, I'd also want to know whether the behaviour of allMatch() suited my customer's requirement.

Comment: Sure, if you don't trust that your customers know what they're talking about, you could ask them :-). Although, do you have a legitimate example where one wants to know about "all" and wants to treat "there aren't any" as invalid? For example if you end a prorgram with "assert(allFileHandlesAreClosed())", would you really want that to fail when no files were opened in the first place? Or when you hold a lecture and request "all phones turned off", would you really have an issue if nobody had a phone at all? No, those cases are clearly ok. Do you have an example where it's not?

Comment: I'm not going to extend this discussion past the point where the site starts suggesting moving to chat so won't be replying further. In my experience, assuming that I know the intent of my customer when I haven't had it explicitly stated is a mistake, even if the assumed intent seems logical. A customer's expectation of the handling of an empty list may not equate to the one you propose. So I would want to clarify that. That's all I'm saying.

Comment: I agree that short doesn't mean better, but I don't think nowadays checked exceptions is the way to go, I think the industry has learnt they simply does not work the way they expected when were introduced, they are probably still valid in certain cases (I don't see a case actually I would introduce a checked exception). 
Most authors and developers are moving away from them and particularly in java and modern languages the trend is to not using them.

Answer (score -1):

There are 3 exit-points for your method:

1. if the argument is `null` (can't judge the sign of elements)
2. if the argument is empty (can't judge the sign of elements)
3. if the argument contains at least one element (can easily multiply to get accumulated sign)

#### Arithmetical (binary) approach

Here is the implementation I would suggest from a different perspective: *arithmetical* using only the sign, exactly the sign-bit:

```java
static boolean containsOnlyNegatives(int[] integers) {
  // so called guard-statement first as fail-fast
  if (integers == null || integers.length == 0) {
    // though strictly non-negative; consider throwing IllegalArgumentException
    return false;
  }

  // bitwise AND (&) operation results true only if negative sign given
  // put -1 as reference for comparison (negative sign)
  var signedResult = IntStream.of(integers).reduce(-1, (a, b) -> a & b); 

  return Integer.signum(signedResult) == -1;
}
```

Notice how I changed the method-name to sound like a *predicate* or *matcher* (idiomatic naming-convention like `is/has/contains`; compare *Hamcrest* matchers).

Here is a [demo on IDEone](https://ideone.com/jhBeHY) which uses a simple for-loop.

#### Why arithmetical instead of iteration using predicates ?

Bitwise arithmetics are usually the fastest operations for a CPU (hopefully the Java compiler can optimize as such)

#### When predicate gains performance ?

Assume your list of 1001 integers has the first element as negative and as early as the second element with a positive. Then you could stop after the second element and `return false`. This is concept is also called *short-circuit* or *fail-fast* similar to mathematical/logical dis-prove of an assumption.

Note on Java 8 stream-predicates:

- `allMatch` tests all integers and thus may take longer
- `anyMatch` can stop as soon as first positive detected to prove: not all integers are negative!

So you could improve given functional answer using this  *matcher* and *predicate*:

```java
static boolean containsOnlyNegatives(int[] integers) {
  // similar to answer already given, but short-circuiting and bitwise
  return integers != null 
         && !Arrays.stream(integers).anyMatch(i -> Integer.signum(-1 & i) != -1);
}
```

Reads hard and causes mental load, because all that *diluting negations* made it somewhat complicated.

#### Simplify towards a positive

In your case the method-name has a negative connotation already: `allNegatives`.
When verifying that all are negatives, you also verify that no positive exists.
Try to reverse it - it's easier to read and think on a **positive expression (of intent)**:

```java
static boolean containsPositive(int[] integers) {
  // now short-circuiting if the first element was tested positive 
  return integers != null
         && Arrays.stream(integers).anyMatch(i -> Integer.signum(-1 & i) == 1);
}

// kept for convenience, if you need that contract
static boolean containsOnlyNegatives(int[] integers) {
  return !containsPositive(integers);
}
```

Try the [demo on IDEone](https://ideone.com/0gNMvE)

#### See also

- [Bitwise Operators and Negative Numbers](https://janmr.com/blog/2010/07/bitwise-operators-and-negative-numbers/)
- [java - How can I check whether an array is null / empty? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369967/how-can-i-check-whether-an-array-is-null-empty)
- [Java Stream anyMatch() Tutorial With Examples | kheri.net](https://kheri.net/java-stream-anymatch/)

Comment: Sorry, 12 hours work-day (bug-fixing, code-review) ... the issue challenged my assembly-origins. Think I have iterated to a better solution now. Although _bit-ops_ are not everyone's favorite, the __positive__ intent should win readers 

Comment: Is Array.stream() going to be compiled into for loop with some optimization like SIMD or something, or is it some object which calls callbacks? If it is the other one, would it not kill the performance?